# How to run command with administrator privileges

Tags: swift, macos, command-line

I want to implement a simple mac app which will run some commands with administrator privileges.
What I've done is the code below

```
func execute(command: String) -> String {
        var arguments:[String] = []
        arguments.append("-c")
        arguments.append(command)

        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
        task.arguments = arguments

        let pipe = Pipe()
        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.standardError = pipe
        task.launch()
        task.waitUntilExit()
        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()

        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    }
```

This is working for commands without `sudo`, when I'm putting sudo in the beginning of command I get this error `/bin/sh: /usr/bin/sudo: Operation not permitted`

I just want somehow to give the user's password or ask it native? 
Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could run your app as sudo, this should hand down the priviledges to the child processes.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment but that doesn't suit me

Comment: This will be a mac app I dont want user to see the terminal

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, keep the code as it is and the command should be in this format:

```
"osascript -e 'do shell script \"my command\" with administrator privileges'"
```

I tried to use it before but I had to put quotes and single quotes as above!

With that the native alert of apple is presenting.